# Problem while using gdal_translate command through command prompt

Tags: gdal

I am trying to geo-reference a raw satellite image using the following the code through command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\PRODUCT1>gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 2458.0 2464.0. 81.2273 21.2776 -gcp 1.0 4928.0 81.0854 21.1940 -gcp 4917.0 4928.0 81.3161 21.1443 -gcp 4917.0 1.0 81.3694 21.3612 -gcp 1.0 1.0 81.1383 21.4109 Imagery.L-4 tmp.tif
```

After running the above code I am getting the following:

```
Input file size is 4917, 4928
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...ERROR 3: Read of 4917 bytes for scanline 4928 failed.

ERROR 1: Imagery.L-4, band 3: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 4927
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 0, Y block offset 4927
```

Can somebody tell what could be the issue & how it can be rectified?

Comment: @user2856....Thanks for your suggestion....but I am getting same error after incorporating it as: gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 --config GTIFF_IGNORE_READ_ERRORS YES -gcp 2458.0 2464.0. 81.2273 21.2776 -gcp 1.0 4928.0 81.0854 21.1940 -gcp 4917.0 4928.0 81.3161 21.1443 -gcp 4917.0 1.0 81.3694 21.3612 -gcp 1.0 1.0 81.1383 21.4109 Imagery.L-4 tmp.tif. Also I want to tell you that when I am opening this ".L-4 file" in ArcGIS all the 3 bands are opening perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps try [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)

Comment: looks like your file is corrupted - try running `gdalinfo` on it but try getting a new copy

Comment: @lanTurton I tried running gdalinfo too on the .L-4 file but landed up on the same error. But my doubt is if the file is corrupted then how come ArcGIS opened up this image without popping up any error. Still I will try getting a new copy of the .L-4 file and check for its correctness. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Today I tried with the new ".L-4 File". But same issue is coming i.e. I am not able to read the third band as an array. Although I am able to compute its statistics just like for other 2 bands.

Comment: GDAL anyway seems to think that the image is corrupted. Share the image if you can. If the data is confidential you can perhaps edit the pixels with ArcGIS so that you can share the edited version, if it still triggers the error.

Comment: @user30184..Due to security constraints I will not be able to share the image. I would like to inform that the image is in Bit interleaved by line (BIL) format with 540 bytes of header information. Is this information sufficient to proceed further or if any other information is required then do let me know.